# У меня проблема с кодом python

Tags: python-3.5

В общем я взял код, вставил в него свои данные и после чего попытался запустить. Вроде данные правильные а всеравно выдает ошибку.

Код этот для загрузки фото в группу вконтакте:

```
import vk_api


def main():


    login, password = '+7999******', '***********'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk_session.authorization()
    except vk_api.AuthorizationError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return

    """
        В VkUpload реализованы методы загрузки файлов в ВК.
        (Не все, если что-то понадобится - могу дописать)
    """
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)

    photo = upload.photo(  # Подставьте свои данные
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\images',
        album_id=147060453,
        group_id=245815717
    )

    vk_photo_url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJ4trx_zWOPt7l-tvBiM5RJrcdBQtgd-_zTRv4LmmnleHV-UYl1w'.format(
        photo[0]['-147060453'], photo[0]['1']
    )

    print(photo, '\nLink: ', vk_photo_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 137
    DeprecationWarning
DeprecationWarning: Please replace `VkApi.authorization` with `VkApi.auth` and `AuthorizationError` with `AuthError`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\VK API.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\VK API.py", line 25, in main
    group_id=245815717
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\upload.py", line 45, in photo
    url = self.vk.method('photos.getUploadServer', values)['upload_url']
  File "C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 450, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [200] Access denied
```

Comment: Вместо ссылки на картинку с ошибкой, лучше поправьте вопрос и добавьте в него проблемый код и текст ошибки (трассу стека)

Comment: Ну а вот и ошибка: `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [200] Access denied` возникает в VkUpload. Еще путь в `'C:\Program Files (x86)\images'` должен иметь экранирование слешей, иначе после будет ругаться на неправильный путь

Comment: Обратите внимание,что в сообщении _DeprecationWarning: Please replace `VkApi.authorization` with `VkApi.auth` and `AuthorizationError` with `AuthError`_ просят заменить `VkApi.authorization`на `VkApi.auth`и `AuthorizationError` на `AuthError` может и доступ будет разрешен